# NAudio play IEEEFloat format

Tags: c#, .net, audio, microphone, naudio

Input source is a microphone connected via national instruments. Incoming signal format is (IEEEFloat, 51200 Samples per second, 100ms read cycle)  and is represented as an array `double[] samples`. For every 100ms, there is a incoming signal from the microphone as a double[]. How to play this signal using default soundcard in a windows machine.

```
public void Open()
{
   var _format = new WaveFormatChunk
                 {
                   SamplesPerSecond = Convert.ToUInt32(51200),
                   BitsPerSample = 32,
                   Channels = 1,
                   FormatEncoding = WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat
                 };

   _waveOutDevice = new WaveOut
                    {
                      DesiredLatency = 100
                    };

   _waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(_format.ToWaveFormat());

   _waveOutDevice.Init(WaveProvider);
}

public void Consume(double[] samples)
{
     var bytes = samples.ToBytes();               

     _waveProvider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

public void Play()
{
     _waveOutDevice.Play();
}
```

Only sound heared can be some kind of click (pin pricking soung) every 100ms. No voice or any other sound can be heared from the microphone. Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfect. My mistake. My Inputs were not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have missed the conversion from 64-bit IEEE Float to 32-bit IEEE Float...  Aside from that, the code looks reasonable.